# sudo -A ignoring my SUDO_ASKPASS variable

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu, sudo

### sudo -A ignoring SUDO_ASKPASS variable

I have been using `sudo -A` and `SUDO_ASKPASS` for years without trouble.

I have a newly installed Xubuntu Focal Fossa workstation and I cannot get `sudo -A` to work

I have:

```
me@mine:~$ cat .ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'SECRET'

me@mine:~$ ll .ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh
-rwx------ 1 me me 27 Apr 25 10:25 .ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh*

me@mine:~$ cat .bash_profile 
SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh

me@mine:~$ source .bash_profile 

me@mine:~$ echo ${SUDO_ASKPASS}
/home/me/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh

me@mine:~$ ${SUDO_ASKPASS}
SECRET

me@mine:~$ sudo -A reboot now
sudo: no askpass program specified, try setting SUDO_ASKPASS

me@mine:~$
```

**What on earth have I forgotten?**

Comment: Did you `export` it anywhere? what does `declare -p SUDO_ASKPASS` report?

Comment: GENIUS!!!!   I change the ```.bash_profile``` line from ```SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh``` to ```export SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh``` and it works!  Write it up as the answer and I'll do all the hearts and flowers stuff.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SUDO_ASKPASS` variable needs to be exported to your environment, rather than defined as a simple shell variable:

```
export SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh
```

or POSIXly

```
SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.ssh/secrets/.supwd.sh
export SUDO_ASKPASS
```

Comment: Much obliged! Thanks!