# Help with 'sudo --askpass' on Ubuntu / Apache2 Server

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, sudo

I need help with a `sudo -A` command in a shell script.  The -A option is for AskPass.  According to the [sudo man page](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.14/sudo.man/):

> Normally, if sudo requires a password, it will read it from the user's
> terminal.  If the -A (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly
> graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and
> output the password to the standard output.  If the SUDO_ASKPASS
> environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper
> program.

I'm interested in AskPass because I'm running apache2 (v 2.4.41) on a Ubuntu 16.04 server.  The Apache webpage needs to execute a shell script.  The webpage executes the script as user `www-data`.  But the script needs to run another program that can only be run as user `user1`.  So I need `sudo --AskPass` so that user `www-data` can run user `user1`'s code.

My setup:  Following such examples as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333850/sudo-a-ignoring-my-sudo-askpass-variable) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750419/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-needing-password-input-in-the-background), I've written these two scripts in the `/var/www/html/` directory:

```
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1   www-data   TestUsers    29 Feb 28 11:34 passwdScript.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1   www-data   TestUsers  2009 Feb 28 11:32 webpageScript.sh
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
```

(Group `TestUsers` includes users `www-data` and `user1`.)  The little `passwdScript.sh` script is meant to send user1's password to STD OUT:

```
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$ more passwdScript.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'myPassword'
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$ ./passwdScript.sh
myPassword
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
```

(Yes, I know this is highly insecure, but I will be the only person using this server.  I'm worried about functionality only.)

Okay:  Now that the above is set up, here's my `webpageScript.sh` script, which is meant to call `sudo --AskPass`:

```
echo "Script is running."
export SUDO_ASKPASS="/var/www/html/passwdScript.sh"
echo "Test :: $SUDO_ASKPASS"
cd /home/user1/path/to/other/directory
pwd
sudo -u user1 --askpass $SUDO_ASKPASS 'runUser1Script.exe'
echo "Finished running the script."
```

Here's the less-than-impressive output:

```
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$ sudo -u www-data ./webpageScript.sh
Script is running.
Test :: /var/www/html/passwdScript.sh
/home/user1/path/to/other/directory
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
Finished running the script.
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
user1@myUbuntu:/var/www/html$
```

So obviously the `sudo --askpass` command is failing to accept `user1`'s password.  I've been trying variations on that command all day.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed itself End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is that (at least in the default configuration) `sudo` requires the *invoking* user's password - not that of the *target* user

Comment: @steeldriver So when my script runs as `www-data` and then reaches command `sudo -u user1 --askpass $SUDO_ASKPASS 'runUser1Script.exe' ` , AskPass should be suppling `www-data`'s password, not `user1`'s?  Wow.  You just blew my mind...!

Comment: @Pete yes I believe so - unless you have set `targetpw` on in your sudo config. See `man sudoers`.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm